# JavaScript - Convert 24 digit hexadecimal number to decimal, add 1 and then convert back?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hex, largenumber

For an ObjectId in MongoDB, I work with a 24 digit hexadecimal number. Because I need to keep track of a second collection, I need to add 1 to this hexadecimal number.

In my case, here's my value

```
var value = "55a98f19b27585d81922ba0b"
```

What I'm looking for is

```
var newValue = "55a98f19b25785d81922ba0c"
```

I tried to create a function for this

```
function hexPlusOne(hex) {
    var num = (("0x" + hex) / 1) + 1;
    return num.toString(16);
}
```

This works with smaller hex numbers

```
hexPlusOne("eeefab")
=> "eeefac"
```

but it fails miserably for my hash

```
hexPlusOne(value)
=> "55a98f19b275840000000000"
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version will return a string as long as the input string, so the overflow is ignored in case the input is something like "ffffffff".

```js
function hexIncrement(str) {
    var hex = str.match(/[0-9a-f]/gi);
    var digit = hex.length;
    var carry = 1;

    while (digit-- && carry) {
        var dec = parseInt(hex[digit], 16) + carry;
        carry = Math.floor(dec / 16);
        dec %= 16;
        hex[digit] = dec.toString(16);
    }
    return(hex.join(""));
}

document.write(hexIncrement("55a98f19b27585d81922ba0b") + "<BR>");
document.write(hexIncrement("ffffffffffffffffffffffff"));
```

This version may return a string which is 1 character longer than the input string, because input like "ffffffff" carries over to become "100000000".

```js
function hexIncrement(str) {
    var hex = str.match(/[0-9a-f]/gi);
    var digit = hex.length;
    var carry = 1;

    while (digit-- && carry) {
        var dec = parseInt(hex[digit], 16) + carry;
        carry = Math.floor(dec / 16);
        dec %= 16;
        hex[digit] = dec.toString(16);
    }
    if (carry) hex.unshift("1");
    return(hex.join(""));
}

document.write(hexIncrement("55a98f19b27585d81922ba0b") + "<BR>");
document.write(hexIncrement("ffffffffffffffffffffffff"));
```

I was curious te see whether user2864740's suggestion of working with 12-digit chunks would offer any advantage. To my surprise, even though the code looks more complicated, it's actually around twice as fast. But the first version runs 500,000 times per second too, so it's not like you're going to notice in the real world.

```js
function hexIncrement(str) {
    var result = "";
    var carry = 1;
    while (str.length && carry) {
        var hex = str.slice(-12);
        if (/^f*$/i.test(hex)) {
            result = hex.replace(/f/gi, "0") + result;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            result = ("00000000000" + (parseInt(hex, 16) + carry).toString(16)).slice(-hex.length) + result;
            carry = 0;
        }
        str = str.slice(0,-12);
    }
    return(str.toLowerCase() + (carry ? "1" : "") + result);
}

document.write(hexIncrement("55a98f19b27585d81922ba0b") + "<BR>");
document.write(hexIncrement("000000000000ffffffffffff") + "<BR>");
document.write(hexIncrement("0123456789abcdef000000000000ffffffffffff"));
```

Comment: Someone edited the answer to increment "ffff" into "10000", but I'm not sure the OP wants to change the number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from attempting to covert the entire 24-digit hex value to a number first because it won't fit in the range of integers JavaScript can represent distinctly<sup>2</sup>. In doing such a conversion to a JavaScript number some accuracy is lost.

However, it can be processed as multiple (eg. two) parts: do the math on the right part and then the left part, if needed due to overflow<sup>1</sup>. (It could also be processed one digit at a time with the entire addition done manually.)

Each chunk can be 12 hex digits in size, which makes it an easy split-in-half.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, if the final num for the right part is larger than 0xffffffffffff, simply carry over (adding) one to the left part. If there is no overflow then the left part remains untouched.

<sup>2</sup> See [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

The range is 2^53, but the incoming value is 16^24 ~ (2^4)^24 ~ 2^(4*24) ~ 2^96; still a valid number, but outside the range of integers that can be distinctly represented.

---

Also,  use `parseInt(str, 16)` instead of using `"0x" + str` in a numeric context to force the conversion, as it makes the intent arguably more clear.

Comment: I tried the per-12-digit version (see my answer) and to my surprise it's twice as fast as the per-digit version. I thought it wouldn't make much difference because most random input strings only require the change of one or two digits.